# How to get user email, public_profile from facebook access_token

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8

I'm building a windows phone 8.1 app that allow user to login facebook account.

There is my code:

```
string productId = "myproductid";

string facebookAppId = "myfacebookappid";
string redirectUri = "msft-"+productId+"://authorize";
string scope = "public_profile,email"; // What you want to fetch from the facebook user
string responseType = "token"; // Other response types possible

UriBuilder authUri = new UriBuilder("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth");
authUri.Query = "client_id=" + facebookAppId + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri + "&scope=" + scope + "&response_type=" + responseType;

var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uriToLaunch);
```

And code in App.xaml.cs:

```
    protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnActivated(args);


        if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuation)
        {
            App.MobileService.LoginComplete(args as WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs);
        }
        if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
        {
            ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;

            WwwFormUrlDecoder decoder = new WwwFormUrlDecoder(eventArgs.Uri.Fragment);

            string fbAccessToken = decoder.GetFirstValueByName("#access_token");

            /* Now you can use the access token to interact with the Facebook API */
        }

    }
```

But how to get user's email and profile from "fbAccessToken"?

Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the graph APIs of facebook

graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={0}

Please refer this link - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3

Answer (score -1):

Add scope/Extended Permission to get user profile etc.,

```
string scope ="user_about_me,read_stream,publish_actions,user_birthday,offline_access,email"
```

Comment: He just wants `public_profile` and `email` as mentioned in the question!

Comment: This will help to others in future.. That's why I add all the permissions which I know.!